# JQ - Recursive JSON return parent

Tags: json, jq, parent, recursive-datastructures

I'm tryng to return a parent in this kind of json using JQ:

```
{
    "all" : {
        "text": "a",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "aa",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "text": "ab",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "text": "ac",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "aca",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "acb",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "acc",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "text": "acca",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The goal is to retrieve the parent text for an element.
For example:

- searching acca --> acc
- searching  acc --> ac

This code doesn't work:
`.all  | .children[] as $parent | select(.children[].text == "acca" )  | $parent.text`

Someone can help me?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Get the path to the string you're looking for, retrieve the path to its grand grandparent out of it, and extract `text` from there.

```
getpath(
  paths(strings
    | select(. == "acca")
  )[:-3]
) .text
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KIws-K6WMq)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a succinct, parameterized solution that does not require explicit use of `recurse`:

```
paths(objects | select(.text == $needle)) as $p
| getpath($p[:-2]).text
```

Example usage:

```
jq --arg needle acca -f program.jq input.json
```

(Notice that there might not be any need to quote the "needle".)

Comment: Man, I totally forgot about `paths`

Comment: Is `recurse` implicitly used ? Are there any concerns in using `recurse` ?

Comment: Yes, and no (or if you prefer, not really).  The reason for the "no" is that `recurse` is defined in a way that benefits from jq's TCO (tail-call optimization).